# Semantic-ui-css, how do I disable web fonts when building with webpack/npm?

Tags: webpack, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using `Semantic-ui-react` and it works well. I import the `semantic.min.css` from the `semantic-ui-css` npm module.

However, it's making external calls to the internet using web fonts which I really do not want.

I could go into the .css file itself and remove them but that's hard-coded and bad practice since building it on another machine from npm modules would result in it doing it again.

Is there a way to disable all web fonts, for example when building it with Webpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only sensible way to do this, you should build a custom SUI. Here is official guide about [theming](http://learnsemantic.com/themes/creating.html).

In fact you should edit only `importGoogleFonts` variable that located in [site.variables](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/577ae996568e355cb0141a7cce9ba07bec2ceceb/src/themes/default/globals/site.variables#L16). There is [awesome guide](http://neekey.net/2016/12/09/integrate-react-webpack-with-semantic-ui-and-theming/) about setup semantic-ui-less and webpack. But, if you're using create-react-app I will recomend to use SUI's build system.